# Laurent expansion question

Tags: laurent-series

[image]

I'm quite stuck on how to solve this using the Laurent expansion as the denominator is simply $z^3$ rather than something like $1-z$

***separate question!***

[image]

I'm not too sure how to solve this, I've found that for $|z|<1$ we have $$i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{z}{i}\bigg)^n$$
however, how would I find the summation for $|z|>0$?

Comment: what i think is to use partial fraction, then use $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$

Comment: For the first one it is straightforward. For the second one you need to use partial fraction.

Comment: could you elaborate?